# A question about hypothesis in a lemma on Valuation Rings (Atiyah-Mcdonald)

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $K$ be a field, $\Omega$ an algebraically closed field. Let $\Sigma$ be the collection of pairs $(A,f)$ where $A$ is subring of $K$ and $f:A\rightarrow \Omega$ is a ring homomorphism. Partially order $\Sigma$ by $(A,f)\le (A'\le f')$ if $A\subseteq A'$ and $f'$ is an extension of $f$. Let $(B,g)$ be a maximal member in this set.

While showing that $B$ is a valuation ring, some lemmas are proved.

**Lemma 1.** $B$ is a local ring with $\mathfrak{m}=\ker g$ the unique maximal ideal. [proof is clear to me]

**Lemma 2.** Let $x\in K^{\times}$. Let $B[x]$ be the subring of $K$ generated by $x$ over $B$, and let $\mathfrak{m}[x]$ be the extension of $\mathfrak{m}$ in $B[x]$. Then either $\mathfrak{m}[x]\neq B[x]$ or $\mathfrak{m}[x^{-1}]\neq B[x^{-1}]$.

**Question:** I didn't understand the hypothesis in Lemma 2. By $B[x]$, do we mean that the polynomial expression in $x$ with coefficients in $B$ and analogous meaning for $\mathfrak{m}[x]$?

---

**Ref:** Introduction to Commutative Algebra by Atiyah-McDonald, p.65

Comment: It means the sub ring generated by $B$ and $x$.

Comment: What about $m[x]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $B[x]$ means the subring of $K$ whose elements are polynomial expressions in $x$ with coefficients in $B$.
As for $\mathfrak{m}[x]$, notice that $\mathfrak{m}$ is no longer an ideal in $B[x]$. The extension of the ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ will be the ideal generated by $\mathfrak{m}$ in $B[x]$. Hence, the elements of $\mathfrak{m}[x]$ will be finite sums of the form $ \sum_{i}p_i(x) a_i$, with $p_i(x) \in B[x]$ and $a_i \in \mathfrak{m}$.

In general, if $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a ring morphism and $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A$, then $f(\mathfrak{a})$ is not necessarily an ideal of $B$. By definition, $\textit{the extension}$ of $\mathfrak{a}$ in $B$ is the ideal generated by $f(\mathfrak{a})$ in $B$.

Have a look at page 9 in Atiyah-Macdonald.